# Is there a way in Google Analytics to report a list of client IDs that visited a landing page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to find a way to report a list of Client IDs (like in the User Explorer) that visited a specific landing page. Does anyone have a good approach?

Comment: This is probably off-topic since it is not a programming question, but unless you either copy the client id to a custom dimension or you have GA360 and pull the data via the BigQuery exports the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks you for the reply and thinking about it, you are right about this being off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ga:clientId` parameter in [Analytics Core Reporting v4 API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports) request to get the desired data.
`ga:clientId` is not documented dimension but it works in API reports at least at the moment. I'd suggest using a separate custom dimension for client ID for future reports since this feature might get deprecated without further notice.
sample request:

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "endDate": "yesterday",
          "startDate": "yesterday"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "ga:clientId"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:landingPagePath"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:sessions"
        }
      ],
      "viewId": "12345678"
    }
  ]
}
```